# Error in System.Xml

Tags: c#, web-services, system.xml

I'm working on an app in **C#**. This app is running on **Win XP SP2** and **SP3**. It has to be connected to a server via a webService. It works for all our customers, except one...

When he wants to log on he has an error :

```
There is an error in XML document(1, 368).
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encondingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encondingStyle)
at System.Web.Service.protocols.SoapHttpClient.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asynCall)
at System.Web.Service.protocols.SoapHttpClient.Invoke(String MehtodeName, Object[] parameters)
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
System.Xml
```

After lots of research I couldn't find anything. I don't know where does it come from.
The customer is on XP, service pack 3, so I don't think it can come from his configuration...

Moreover, if someone can explain me how to get the **XML** frame, that could allow me to know what's wrong with his `System.Xml`.

Comment: Looks like there is an error in the XML document. How does the input look like around position (1, 368)?

Comment: I don't have the customer's System.Xml, and in mine for the line 1 I only have 39 columns... So i don't know what is at the position (1, 368) for the customer...